# msys2 の ssh でeuc-jp環境にリモート接続した場合に文字化けを回避する方法

Tags: bash, ssh, msys2

環境は windows10 pro 64bit に msys2 をインストールし、msys2 のターミナル上から ssh で utf-8 環境にリモート接続した場合は文字化けすることなく対応できている状態です。

今回、リモート接続先の環境が、centos7 で LANG=ja_JP.eucjp となっているため、msys2 の ssh でリモート接続した場合、文字化けが発生します。

そこで以下の質問がありますのでよろしくお願いいたします。

1. msys2 の ssh で言語指定できる方法や間にかませるツール等はあるのでしょうか？ 
   cygwin だとcocot なるツールがありますが、cocot.exe を msys2 のパスの通ったところに配置し実行しましたが、cygwin 関連の dll が必要そうでした。
2. msys2 のssh以外で、euc 対応のリモート接続できるツールはありますでしょうか？
   とりあえずは、teraterm を利用していますが、他におすすめなツール等はありますでしょうか？
3. 別件ですが、リモート接続した場合、接続先に emacs をインストールしているのですが、一部のキー操作（具体的には Ctrl + @等）が反応しません。ターミナル接続の制約だとは思うのですが、対応方法はないのでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`luit`(1) が使えるかもしれません。`luit` も msys2 も使ったことがないので、よくわからんが。

- https://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html
- https://github.com/AlecJY/luit-MSYS2/releases

Comment: お教えいただいた luit で上手く動作しました。luit を pacman にてインストールを行い 「$ luit -encoding eucjp -- ssh <接続先> 」で動作しました。

Answer (score 1):

msys2のデフォルトだとターミナルに**mintty**を使用していると思うので、minttyの文字コード設定をja_JP.eucJPに変更してみてください。

ターミナルを右クリックしてOption -> Text からLocale(ロケール)やCharset(文字コード)を指定できるようです。多少古い記事になりますが、以下のページに実際の変更手順があります。

参考：
[Cygwinのminttyでロケールと文字コードを指定](https://koi000.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2012-02-05-1)

Comment: お教えいただいた方法で上手く動作しました。
できれば接続先別に言語設定を動的に切り替える方法があればよかったと思っています。

Comment: ログイン先によって言語(ロケール)設定が違うということですかね？自分は`mintty`は詳しくないのですが、代わりに例えば`Poderosa`等をSSH接続に使うと接続先ごとに言語設定も含めたショートカットが作成できたりします。 / 必要に応じて別質問に分けてもらうとよいかもしれません (私も可能な範囲で回答します)。

Comment: luit を利用することで希望の動作となりました。